# Place imageview next to textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to place an imageview next to a textview. However they keep ending up on different "lines".

```
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="10dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_fmk_icon" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/medication_administration_time_row_fmk_icon"
      android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_drug" />
```

Placing the image as a compound drawable isn't an option as that is used for another image.

Any clues about how I can get the image on the same line as the text?

Comment: exactly what you want? share some screenshots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to give you some tips when you are trying to make UI of the app. The first thing you should do is to try to get the UI you want using design tool where you can place UI elements and what is more important you can also see which attributes you can set for specific layout. That will save you some time.

And answer to you question would be linear layout which is the most easier way to do it. Just try to avoid weights(here not necessary) because than it takes more time to create UI.

Here is great tutorial to understand layout bit better.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/

And of course answer to your question(did it just by using design tool):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use **android:layout_toRightOf**: 
Positions the left edge of this view to the right of the given anchor view ID. Accommodates left margin of this view and right margin of anchor view.Property of RelativeLayout.So finally,

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_drug"
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_fmk_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptioncomma" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/medication_administration_time_row_drug" />
```

Comment: How come the imageview can have two id ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Use a LinearLayout as container/parent with either vertical or horizontal orientation, what fits your needs.
2. You can use an relative layout as container/parent and then use "toRightOf" or "above"/"below" property and use the ids of your child views.

The better approach is the first one, as relative layout measure twice.

Comment: The best approach is by using **compound drawables**.

Comment: But he don't want to use compound drawables. And regarding my two options the linear layout is the best approach.

Comment: He really **should** always prefer compound drawables. Because it reduces the View count and flattens the layout, resulting in better performances.

Comment: I agree with you. I prefer that too.

Answer (score 0):

Using Compound Drawable

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/medication_administration_time_row_fmk_icon"
  android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_drug"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image_name />
```

In this you setting the `ImageView` to the left of `TextView`

Else if you want this as separate components means try this (Another way of doing)

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageView
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_fmk_icon" />

<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/medication_administration_time_row_fmk_icon"
  android:id="@+id/medication_administration_time_row_drug" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Change the `android:orientation` of `LinearLayout` in case if you want it vertical, accordingly change the `android:gravity` too

Comment: He don't want to use a compound drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTipoProduto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_kit_produtos_white_12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTipoProduto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.04"
                    android:text="@string/kit_de_produtos"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>
```